# var/log/mongodb/mongod.log endless loop of open and close connection from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, logging

Inside `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` I have an endless loop of open and close connection. It's making the mongod.log huge, and taking up the disk space. I'm also concerned there is a faulty code in my node.js application. I am using mongoose and also native mongo driver inside my node js application. I do not see any errors or exceptions.

Has anyone seen this before, and what might be the root cause? The log is now 11GB and keeps growing.

```
2017-07-14T17:51:59.562+0000 I -        [conn21293746] end connection 127.0.0.1:49373 (19 connections now open)
2017-07-14T17:51:59.638+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49374 #21293747 (19 connections now open)
2017-07-14T17:51:59.639+0000 I NETWORK  [conn21293747] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:49374 conn21293747: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "2.2.28" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "3.13.0-117-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v6.10.2, LE, mongodb-core: 2.1.12" }

2017-07-14T17:51:59.641+0000 I -        [conn21293747] end connection 127.0.0.1:49374 (19 connections now open)
2017-07-14T17:52:00.008+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49375 #21293748 (19 connections now open)
2017-07-14T17:52:00.008+0000 I NETWORK  [conn21293748] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:49375 conn21293748: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "2.2.28" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "3.13.0-117-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v6.10.2, LE, mongodb-core: 2.1.12" }
2017-07-14T17:52:00.013+0000 I -        [conn21293748] end connection 127.0.0.1:49375 (19 connections now open)
2017-07-14T17:52:00.547+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49376 #21293749 (19 connections now open)
2017-07-14T17:52:00.548+0000 I NETWORK  [conn21293749] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:49376 conn21293749: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "2.2.28" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "3.13.0-117-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v6.10.2, LE, mongodb-core: 2.1.12" }
2017-07-14T17:52:00.550+0000 I -        [conn21293749] end connection 127.0.0.1:49376 (19 connections now open)
```

some specific node.js code that gets called frequently

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
exports.logSession  = function(payload)
{
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        insertSessionIntoTable(payload, db, function () {
            db.close();
        })

    })

};

function insertSessionIntoTable(payload, db, callback) {
db.collection(collectionName).insertOne(payload, function (err, result) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    logger.verbose("Inserted a document into the collection.");
    callback();
});
```

Comment: add your node.js application code to question.

Comment: exports.logSession  = function(payload)
{
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        insertSessionIntoTable(payload, db, function () {
            db.close();
        })

    })

};

Comment: please add the full connection code update question .

Comment: after updating the question with your suggestion. it seems obvious that this is the problem. i am using the mongo client to connect every function call. this seems wrong. when should i open and close the connection?

Comment: check my answer, open db connection once and use same connection don't clsoe it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code will open connection for every session

```
exports.logSession  = function(payload)
{
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) { // for every session your code will open new connection 
        assert.equal(null, err);
        insertSessionIntoTable(payload, db, function () {
            db.close(); // here it will close it
        })

    })
};
```

open the connection once and use same connection do all the operations.

```
var db;
MongoClient.connect(url)
  .then(function (dbInstance) { // <- db as first argument
    db = dbInstance;
  })
  .catch(function (err) {})

exports.logSession  = function(payload)
{
        insertSessionIntoTable(payload, db, function () {
            // work done
        })

    })
};
```

Comment: thanks that works for me. i implemented it just initalizing the connection once. so I dont ever need to close the db, correct?